# "TALK TO somebody" and "TALK somebody|something"

Tags: grammar, difference

Please explain, is there any difference in such a sentence?

> Talk to him or Talk him

or maybe "Talk him" = 'Talk about him"?

Here are some examples which is why I asked my question.

> 1. I don't nee *(need?)* a haircut **I want to talk her**. ([source](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/I+don%27t+nee+a+haircut+I+want+to+talk+her))
> 2. Whatever we can do for you, Agent Gibbs. Actually **I'd like to talk your wife**. ([source](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/I%27d+like+to+talk+your+wife))
> 3. **We’re talking free exhibition space** in Startup Alley for both days of Disrupt, invitations to private events, backstage access, CrunchMatch — our free business-matching platform — free subscriptions to Extra Crunch and a ticket to all future TechCrunch events. That’s some major value right there. ([source](https://techcrunch.com/2019/08/14/apply-to-startup-battlefield-at-disrupt-berlin-2019/) *fourth paragraph from the bottom*)

To the strange people scoring me negative:
What's wrong? Please say why?

Comment: It looks like your converting the phrase from english to Russian, but the phrase doesn't work in English. Where did you first hear it? Please can you add more context.

Comment: This question looks to me like it's really just asking *Why does **context.reverso.net** make such bad translations from Russian to English?*  That's a software problem, not really about English as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, those are not from Rus->Eng, those are from Eng->Rus. And as I know they take original samples from movies' subtitiles. **Maybe the subtitles themselves have mistakes**. **1 example** Bye.
I don't nee a haircut I want to talk her.
I don't want to.
Why not?
**2 example**
Excuse me.
Baby, what was that?
I don't want to talk her.
Well, what do you want me to say?
I don't know.
**3 example**
Whatever we can do for you, Agent Gibbs.
Thank you.
Actually I'd like to talk your wife.
What about?
I got it up, boss.

Comment: If these are taken from subtitles, it would be better to add the source of the subtitles, or a link to a youtube clip of the scene. You're probably correct about the subtitles having mistakes. It also looks like you've copied the subtitle wrong into your question (1), the one in your comment makes more sense

Comment: @Bee, why did you say that I copied wrong? I can suppose that the subtitkes describe the speech of the foreigners or like that. But what about the third example. That is the native english article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I dont understand why Im getting negative score. According to the answer below, I came across with a real lunguage issue. I didnt make any mistakes. And using TALK without about it's real situation. Look at my 3 example in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb (in this case TO) is required when referencing a person.

*"I need to talk to Alice about the car."*

When a the sentence concerns other nouns that aren't people as the topic of the conversation the verb TO can be left out. The second example you mentioned uses talking to imply a claim. For example you could rephrase the sentence as follows

*"We are **talking** hundreds of people at the party."*

*"We are **claiming there will be** hundreds of people at the party."*

However this exact translation does not always work as sometimes the verb talking simply implies that we are talking about something. For example:

*"Sorry I was late, Jim and I were **talking** cars"*

Is the same as:

*"Sorry I was late, Jim and I were **talking about** cars"*

Another term that comes up sometimes is "talking shop". This is a special use case for the word shop that means talking about their jobs or common technical knowledge and it is really only applied in this context. For example:

Proper: *"Sorry I was late, Jim and I were **talking** shop"*

Not Proper: *"Sorry I was late, Jim and I were **talking about** shop"*

Comment: cool, thanks! :) You mean that "I need to talk Alice about the car" is the same as "I need to talk TO Alice about the car"?

Comment: and even so, what difference, maybe stylistic, is between them? When we leave out ABOUT after Talk. Now, thanks to you, I clearly understand what #3 means. But about your example "Jim and I were talking cars"?

Comment: are you there? Be so good do answer my comments :)

Comment: You need the word to between talk and the name of the person you are talking to. As for the 3rd example you could use this when you are talking about a subject, in this case cars.